# Identificação de User Control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Estou tentando utilizar um User Control com `VB` e está criado da seguinte forma:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SigaFormacao.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="SigaFormacao" %>
```

Página que utiliza o User Control:

```
<%@ Register Src="../PortalControls/SigaFormacao.ascx" TagName="SigaFormacao" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

(...)

<uc1:SigaFormacao ID="SigaFormacao1" runat="server" />
```

Código:

```
Dim gv As GridView = CType(SigaFormacao1.FindControl("GVFormacao"), GridView);
```

Linha onde acusa "SigaFormacao1" não está declarado. Ele pode estar inacessível devido ao seu nível de proteção. E isso dá erro de compilação

Comment: Tem que colocar a pagina toda, não tem como dizer assim, e se dentro desse componente tem um GridView precisamos saber como você está fazendo esse `control`, então, poste tudo.